# JSP Servlet Null Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have problem with my simple project (using JSP).
When I try to run my servlet, I have this message:

```
Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.NullPointerException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it 
from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.dentapp.web.jdbc.PatientControllerServlet.doGet(PatientControllerServlet
   .java:42)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.dentapp.web.jdbc.PatientDBUtil.getPatients(PatientDBUtil.java:28)
com.dentapp.web.jdbc.PatientControllerServlet.listPatients(PatientController
Servlet.java:50)
com.dentapp.web.jdbc.PatientControllerServlet.doGet(PatientControllerServlet
.java:40)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

I have no idea what i've done wrong. I've tried to take the data from connected database (it's filled of course) and i've got this exception.

Here is my code: 
1) Patient Class

```
public class Patient {

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;

public Patient(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Patient{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

2) PatientDBUtil

```
public class PatientDBUtil {

private DataSource dataSource;

public PatientDBUtil(DataSource theDataSource){
    dataSource = theDataSource;
}

public List<Patient> getPatients() throws Exception{

    List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();

    Connection myConn=null;
    Statement myStmt= null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;

    try {
        //get a connection
        myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

        // create sql statment
        String sql = "select id_pacjenta, imie, nazwisko, email from pacjent 
 order by nazwisko";
        //execute query
        myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        // process result set
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);
        // close JDBC objects
        while(myRs.next()){

            // retrieve data from result set row
            int id = myRs.getInt("id_pacjenta");
            String firstName = myRs.getString("imie");
            String lastName = myRs.getString("nazwisko");
            String email = myRs.getString("email");
            //create new patient object
            Patient tempPatient = new Patient(id, firstName, lastName, 
  email);
            //add it to the list of patients
            patients.add(tempPatient);
        }
        return patients;
    }

    finally{
        //close JDBC objects
        close(myConn, myStmt, myRs);


    }
}

private void close(Connection myConn, Statement myStmt, ResultSet myRs) {

    try{
        if(myRs !=null){
            myRs.close();
        }
        if(myStmt !=null){
            myStmt.close();
        }
        if(myConn !=null){
            myConn.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

And here comes the PatientControllerServlet.

```
@WebServlet(name = "PatientControllerServlet")
public class PatientControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

private PatientDBUtil patientDBUtil;

private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();

    //create our patient db util .. and pass in the conn pool /datasource

    try{
        patientDBUtil = new PatientDBUtil(dataSource);
    }

    catch (Exception exc){
        throw new ServletException(exc);
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // list the patients .. in MVC fashion

    try {
        listPatients(request, response);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new ServletException(exc);
    }

}

private void listPatients(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws Exception {

    // get patients from db util
    List<Patient> patients = patientDBUtil.getPatients();
    // add patients to the request

    request.setAttribute("PATIENT_LIST", patients);

    //send to JSP page (view)

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/list_patients.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

 }
}
```

I'm brand new in this technology, and i don't understand what is the mistake here.

Comment: Check the `init` method. You are creating `new PatientDBUtil(dataSource)` and `dataSource` is null.

Comment: You're right! I've missed "@Resource" ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: please answer your question and mark it as solved :)